# Have Darker shadow around corners

Tags: css

I have looked and can't seem to find if it is possible to have darker box shadow around the corners. I know you can do with a .png, but is it possible to do this only with css?

I attached a picture to give an example of what I am trying to accomplish.[image]

```css
.box {
  background-color: #dedede;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(177, 176, 176, 0.74);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> </div>
```

Comment: Darker than what? what does your css look like?

Comment: Are these [the shadows](http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html) that you are looking for?

Comment: go on google and look for css shadow generator should do you the job.

Comment: @Zerp Bram answered my question about the shadow I was trying to acheive. I inserted a example snippet to show you what mine were originally.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before,
.effect2:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot to copy and paste the .box class as well.